# Reading Basic Authentication Credentials sent via the URL

Tags: vb.net, rest, authentication

I know that I can pass basic Authentication credentials via the URL like this:

http://User1:Password@localhost:1234/test

which should put the User1:Password into the Authorization header of the Request.

But when I try and read the Authorization header it is nothing.  I'm doing this in vb.net (when I add the "Basic User1:Password" to my Authentication Header, I can see it coming through in my code).

I'm using HTTP not HTTPS for my testing and I've tried doing this just with a Browser request (IE11) and via ta HTTPWebRequest in vb.net and get the same issue.  I had read that most browsers don't allow adding the Basic Authentication to the URL.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you necessarily have to use that format ? Why not use POST request?

Comment: I do... a long story short, it is for requesting a Delegated UI which is part of the OSLC Spec that is setting the src of an iFrame to a html page that needs authorization to view